# Virtuell Packages keept back when updating

Tags: ubuntu, apt

the one or other might have seen this message when working with apt:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
    some-package
```

The usual solution to this *problem* is to manually install the package:

```
apt-get install some-package
```

But, why does apt holds back the given package in the first place?

For my current case, I was able to reproduce this message: If *some-package* is a virtual package (so it does not contain any data but a control file with dependencies) this happens every time, a dependency is added to the virtual package.
Exampl:
   some-package is a Virtual package, Version 1.0.0 and depends on package-A and package-B

Installing some-package 1.0.0 will also install package-A and package-B.
If I now create a new version of some-package 1.1.0 which depends on package-A, package-B and package-C, and try

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

The result is the above mentioned message:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
    some-package
```

Anybody an idea, why apt holds such packages back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, apt-get upgrade will only upgrade packages that have not had any changes to their dependencies. In this way it is guaranteed that no other packages get installed or, more importantly, removed that other software, uncontrolled by apt, could depend on. In other words, apt is trying to provide maximum stability to your system.

In order to upgrade those additional packages, run

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will first of all display all of the changes that will be made. You can then abort this and use the list of displayed packages to figure out whether these changes will be safe on your system.
Once you have satisfied yourself that the changes that will be OK, run the dist-upgrade for good.